# Laravel - How to pass variable as parameter to external API using guzzle

Tags: laravel, api, guzzle

I am using Laravel-5.8 and Guzzle to consume an external api:

```
public  function index()
{
    try{
    $myparam = 'JKK123';
    $client = new Client();
    $res = $client->request('GET','https://examplet/tracking/$myparam', [
       'query' => ['key' => 'jkkffd091']
   ])->getBody();
    $geoLocation = json_decode($res->getContents(), true);
    $currentLocation = collect($geoLocation)->sortByDesc(function ($data) {
        return Carbon::parse($data['Timestamp'])->format('d-m-Y h:i:s');
    })->first();  

    $currentLocationFilter = explode(',', $currentLocation['current_asset_position_coord'] ?? '');
    dd($currentLocationFilter);
    return view('index', [
        'currentLocation' => $currentLocation,
        'currentLocationFilter' => $currentLocationFilter,
        'geoLocation' => $geoLocation
    ]);
    }catch (Exception $exception) {
        Log::error($exception);
        return back();
    }
}
```

I am trying to pass the variable as parameter to the API. I didn't put it directly because it changes. I just tried to test.

When I did this as shown in the code above

> $res = $client->request('GET','https://examplet/tracking/$myparam', [ ...

and then

> dd($currentLocationFilter);

I got:

```
array:1 [▼
 0 => ""
]
```

But when I put the value directly,

> $res = $client->request('GET','https://examplet/tracking/JKK123', [

I got the required result:

```
 array:2 [▼
  0 => "2.1234565432145"
  1 => "1.7864321249555"
]
```

How do I paa the variable as parameter into the external API?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [double quotes for executing variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) like this:

```
$res = $client->request('GET',"https://examplet/tracking/{$myparam}", [...
```